# How to convert two lists into two dimensional array in selenium c#

Tags: java, c#, arrays

How to convert 2 lists into two dimensional array!

My intention to store links and values in two dimensional array and read from for loop or for each loop.
I have tried doing this but getting failed, your help is highly appreciated.

There are various ways to do to but my intention to learn how to store in two dimensional array,

```
namespace Arry
{

   class Program
   {
      static void Main(string[] args)
      {

        IWebDriver driver = null;
        driver = new ChromeDriver();

        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.google.com/");

        IList<IWebElement> links = driver.FindElements(By.TagName("a"));
         IList<IWebElement> values = driver.FindElements(By.TagName("href"));
        IWebElement[,] res = new IWebElement[links.Count,values.Count];





            foreach (IWebElement link in res)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(link.Text);                
            }               

        Console.Read();            
      }
    }
 }
```

Comment: Please show us some sample lists and the two dimensional array you want to create based on those two lists.

Comment: A 2 dimensional array of width and length `n` holds `n^2` elements while your 2 lists hold `2n` elements. Are you looking for `List<Tuple<IWebElement, IWebElement>>` instead? Maybe try making a class to store these values instead and use `List<MyClass>`

Answer (score 0):

```
int[][] arrays = lst.Select(a => a.ToArray()).ToArray();
```